# Can the language of squares be described by a PEG?

Tags: formal-languages

I believe that they can't, but I couldn't find any existing framework for [parsing expression grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) akin to the pumping lemma that would allow me to prove it.

The language I'm talking about is

$$\{ww\mid w\in\{a, b\}^*\} $$

Can you help me prove it, or find a PEG grammar that parses the language?

Comment: I search papers on PEG and I spent time thinking about it. But if you can give me some concrete direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think that the language is context free or not?

Comment: @adrianN, it's not context free. I'm a bit confused by your question. This is not a homework and I've completed a CS major if that's why you're probing.

Comment: @adrianN, I mean, is the solution obvious and I'm missing it?

Comment: Some useful background: it is known that there exist languages that are parseable by a PEG but aren't context-free (e.g., $\{a^n b^n c^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$).  The class of languages accepted by a PEG is closed under union, intersection, and complement.  It is an open question whether there exists any context-free language that can't be parsed by a PEG grammar; the original paper on PEG grammars conjectured that there does.  See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52224/755.

Comment: Hypothesis: the language is inherently ambiguous, and if that is the case, then there is no PEG that defines it.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos, thanks, I see two problems. First, I believe I can produce non-erasing grammar for the language that has exactly one derivation for each string, second, there are inherently ambiguous languages that can be described by a PEG (e.g. $\{a^nb^mc^md^n\}\cup\{a^nb^nc^md^m\}$).